# How to get list of tags with NGit

Tags: c#, git, ngit

I'm using NGit and I want to get a list of all tags of my current working branch. So I created a NGit instance like this:

`var git = Git.Open("c:\\temp\\projectx");`

Now I want to get a list of all tags in the git archive, but how? There is no command like: `var refs =Git.TagList().Call();`

I would expect that there is a something like BranchList()...
`var refs = Git.BranchList().SetListMode(ListBranchCommand.ListMode.ALL).Call();`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var tags = Git.Open("c:\\temp\\projectx").GetRepository().GetTags();
```

where tags is `IDictionary<string,Ref>`